# Closed formula for computing power for AMOVA test?

Tags: statistical-significance, statistical-power, genetics

I'm doing a retrospective analysis of some genetic data.

1. Does there exist a closed formula for statistical power for AMOVA test?
2. If not, could anyone advise how to compute statistical power for AMOVA test?

Some additional info:
AMOVA - Analysis of MOlecular VAriance. (Do not mistake it with ANOVA!)

Data: 7 populations, 3 subpopulations, 485 samples all together.
Microsatelite data looks like this - haploid, 5 alleles (0 means allele missing):

Pop1 485 254 125 368 0 
Pop1 262 354 125 0 342 
... 
Pop2 470 342 125 368 0 
... 
... 
Pop7 460 451 213 0 487 
...

Population vs. Subpopulation info:

Sub1  Sub2  Sub3
  Pop1    6     71    0 
Pop2    0       9    0 
Pop3    0    86    60 
Pop4    0    45    30 
Pop5    0    12    18 
Pop6    0    87     8 
Pop7    0    18    35

Here's the latest R [package for AMOVA (not ANOVA)](https://grunwaldlab.github.io/Population_Genetics_in_R/AMOVA.html)

AMOVA was introduced in 1992, [here's the original paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1205020/pdf/ge1312479.pdf)

Comment: @Michael There is a statistical model called [AMOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_molecular_variance).

Comment: Okay I found AMOVA on this site Analysis of Molecular Variance.  @whuber I guess that since it involves genetic data it probably is AMOVA but we still need the OP to tell us if anyone will help with this problem.

Comment: I suppose this is now clear enough to be reopened, but I suspect the whole of the answer is "No".

Comment: Little bit surprised to hear all the "What is AMOVA?" comments. Pretty sure I heard this being used fairly frequently for years.

Comment: @Fomite You're right. AMOVA is quite widely used in population genetics. Maybe this is not the right forum for this question?